# is there a way to detect video calls/calls and block them?

Tags: android

I want to prevent cheating in my game and prevent the players to call their friends in game and tell them their roles, I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: They could just use two phones

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent users from communicating with each other. If you were to block calls, they could just use any other form of communication (Instant Messaging like Discord or WhatsApp, SMS, pigeon post, etc).